# for loop condition in 2nd clause and no condition in 3rd clause

Tags: c

```
for(i=5;--i;)
 printf("%d ",i);
```

The output I am getting is proper which is 4 3 2 1. There is no i>0 condition in 3rd clause, so how is loop stopping when i=0?

Comment: The loop could just as well have been written `for (i = 4; i != 0; --i)` to show that the output starts at 4. Now it is just too clever, which some people believe is cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C , false value is represented by 0 whereas any nonzero value indicates true.  In this loop --i; acts as a condition. When i  becomes 0, it acts as a false Boolean value and the loop terminates.

Answer (score 0):

`--i` eventually turns out to be `0`. And thus the condition becomes false.

As, the "3rd clause" is empty, nothing interesting happens. The "2nd clause" is where condition checks are done. And `--i` evaluates to itself which is `0` in the fifth iteration.

Comment: So loop automatically terminates when i=0?Does it treat it as false?

Comment: @RajeshR Yes, the condition becomes `0` or false.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=5;--i;)
 printf("%d ",i);
```

Is equivalent to:

```
for(i=5; --i; i )
     printf("%d ",i);

for(expression1; expression2; expression3 )
     do_something
```

The `for` statement evaluates `expression2` for value 0 to continue executing `do_soemthing`  or not. It will continue till `expression2` == 0;

Answer (score 0):

You didn't noticed that your loop start from 4 instead of 5!

In for statement

```
for (expr1;expr2;expr3)
```

`expr1` executes on the start of loop and will never execute during the iterations

`expr2` is checked for *true* or *any-none-zero-value*; before every iteration if this expression is false or 0 the loop will be stopped.

and `expr3` is executed after the completion of an iteration.

so in your case you don't have any third expression and the second expression which is checked for *0* or *false* will eventually become zero after four iterations